# Let $A,B$ be sets. Show that the three statements $A\subseteq B$, $A\cup B = B$ and $A\cap B = A$ are logically equivalent.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $A,B$ be sets. Show that the three statements $A\subseteq B$, $A\cup B = B$ and $A\cap B = A$ are logically equivalent.

**MY ATTEMPT**

- $A\subseteq B$ $\Rightarrow$ $A\cup B = B$.

> If $x\in A\cup B$, either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. In the first case, due to the assumption, $x\in B$. In the second case, clearly $x\in B$. Thus, in both cases, one has that $x\in B$, which finishes the first part (the inclusion $B\subseteq A\cup B$ is obvious).

- $A\cup B = B \Rightarrow A\cap B = A$.

> If $x\in A\cup B$, either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. In both cases, we conclude that $x\in B$, given that $A\cup B\subseteq B$. Thus, if $x\in A$, we conclude that $x\in B$, due to the fact that $A\cup B\subseteq B$. In other words, $A\subseteq A\cap B$. Since the inclusion $A\cap B\subseteq A$ is obvious, we are done.

- $A\cap B = A \Rightarrow A\subseteq B$.

> If $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cap B$, since we have that $A\subseteq A\cap B$. But then $x\in B$. In other words, if $x\in A$, we have proven that $x\in B$, and the inclusion $A\subseteq B$ holds.

I would like to know if I am reasoning correctly. Can someone check if my argument proceed?

Comment: ```X is equivalent to Y```. you need to show, ```X implies Y and Y implies X```.

Comment: To prove that $X\Leftrightarrow Y\Leftrightarrow Z$ is the same as to prove that $X\Rightarrow Y\Rightarrow Z\Rightarrow X$.

Comment: @Babydesta No, showing $X$ implies $Y$, $Y$ implies $Z$, and $Z$ implies $X$, does prove that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are logical equivalents.

Comment: "X implies Y and Y implies X".  But if $X\implies Y$ and $Y \implies Z$ and $Z\implies X$ then that *DOES* show that $Y\implies Z\implies X$ so the OP *DID* show $Y \implies X$.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct but I'd not accept that the "inclusions are obvious".  You can cite that $M \subset A \cup M$ was an earlier and basic proposition (same thing for $A\cap M \subset A$) or you can prove it in a few words.  But claiming its "obvious" (even though it is) rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @fleablood. You are right, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is convincing.

The second paragraph may need a little polishing.   The reasoning is valid, but a little confusing to follow. Something like:

> Let us prove now that $A\cup B=B$ implies that $A\cap B=A$.   Firstly, $A\cap B\subseteq A$ is obvious.   Secondly, $A\subseteq A\cap B$ is proven thusly: anything in $A$ is in $A\cup B$, which equals $B$ by the premise, so therefore anything in $A$ is both in $A$ and in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

$$A\subseteq B\iff[a\in A\Rightarrow a\in B]\iff[a\in A\Rightarrow a\in A\land a\in B]\iff A\cap B=A$$
$$A\subseteq B\iff[a\in A\Rightarrow a\in B]\iff[a\in A\lor a\in B\iff a\in B]\iff A\cup B=B$$